# PHP CALCULATOR USING BUTTONS

Tags: php, html

HTML CODE :

```
  <div style="padding-left:40px">
    <h2> PHP Calculator</h2>
    <form method="post" action="">

        Enter value: <input type="text" name="value"> <br> <br> 
        <div style="padding-left: 105px">
            <input type="submit" value="9" name="button">
            <input type="submit" value="8" name="button">
            <input type="submit" value="7" name="button">
            <input type="submit" value="+" name="button"> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="6" name="button">
            <input type="submit" value="5" name="button">
            <input type="submit" value="4" name="button">
            <input type="submit" value="-" name="button" style="padding-left: 9px"> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="3" name="button">
            <input type="submit" value="2" name="button">
            <input type="submit" value="1" name="button">
            <input type="submit" value="/" name="button" style="padding-left: 9px"> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="0" name="button" style="padding- left:33px"> 
            <input type="submit" value="." name="button" style="padding-right:9px">
            <input type="submit" value="x" name="button" style="padding left: 7px"><br>
        </div> <br> 
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate" name="Calculator">
    </form>     
   </div>
```

PHP CODE :

```
<?php 

   if (isset($_POST["Calculate"]))
   {
       echo $_POST["button"];
   } ?>
```

I'm developing a PHP calculator, actually my question is when i click to any of the input buttons the value should display in the text box. above is the code what i have tried with, but im unable to get the result. can any one help me in my work,so that how i can get the desired result.

Comment: sounds like you need some javaScript

Comment: sir i know how to do with javascript but im learning PHP n i purely want to build the calculator in PHP only, is their any way to do this please help me

Comment: i would never do this with pure php, you would need to reload the page on every button press, not very user friendly. otherwise stoer the button presses in session .

Comment: actually i have been assigned to do it on PHP only so as to get perfect  in php so im trying it only in php. is their any way?

Comment: At the moment i am learning PHP and i want to understand what is possible and what doesnt work. Ive already found a couple of Javascript Calculators that worked, but nothing with only PHP.

Comment: sure, store click history in a session for determining what to display.

Comment: thank you sir suggestion

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing like you cannot do in PHP but if you could do it using Jquery it will be much more better in terms of User experience as well. Looking at your HTML , I can see you have a input type of submit which means on each click it will submit a form unless and until you have written any condition not to submit. Also your name for each button is also same and it will make difficult to track which one is clicked/entered, please make sure you have unique name field. If you want to do it in PHP only then on every submit you can save that value in session or cookies and while loading page you can check against that session variable or cookies and can show it the the input value. 
You can see following code as a reference but it is using jquery.

```
<div style="padding-left:40px">
    <h2> PHP Calculator</h2>
    <form method="post" action="" id="formID">

        Enter value: <input type="text" name="value" id='btnValue'> <br> <br> 
        <div style="padding-left: 105px">
            <input type="button" value="9" name="btn1">
            <input type="button" value="8" name="btn2">
            <input type="button" value="7" name="btn3">
            <input type="button" value="+" name="btn4"> <br>
            <input type="button" value="6" name="btn5">
            <input type="button" value="5" name="btn6">
            <input type="button" value="4" name="btn7">
            <input type="button" value="-" name="btn8" style="padding-left: 9px"> <br>
            <input type="button" value="3" name="btn8">
            <input type="button" value="2" name="btn9">
            <input type="button" value="1" name="btn10">
            <input type="button" value="/" name="btn11" style="padding-left: 9px"> <br>
            <input type="button" value="0" name="btn12" style="padding- left:33px"> 
            <input type="button" value="." name="btn13" style="padding-right:9px">
            <input type="button" value="x" name="btn14" style="padding left: 7px"><br>
        </div> <br> 
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate" name="Calculator">
    </form>     
   </div>


$('input[type=button]').on('click',function(){
    if($('#btnValue').val()==''){
  $('#btnValue').val($(this).val());
  }else{
 $('#btnValue').val($('#btnValue').val()+($(this).val()));
  }

})
```

Here is the jsfiddle you can look on https://jsfiddle.net/nef1qgzn/13/

Note: I have user Jquery libraray 3.3.1

Comment: he wants pure php, and it can be done in php, not a good idea, but doable

Comment: sir i said na im learning PHP & im assigned the work to do in PHP only so im asking how can we build that in PHP . it may have disadvantages but im just doing it for practice sake, so is their any way please help me .

Comment: I do not know why this has been down voted but  one of the option  so far is using Sessions or Cookies which I had already told. @amitpaple